# database conflict

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, postgresql

i search tricks to know and change the port of oracle, mysql and postgresql database, i mean a dos command or human machine interface.

Comment: Wut? I have no idea what you mean. Please clarify

Comment: DOS? I suspect all three don't work on DOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the server, mysqld, the option is -P

[see: mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html)